# Moving from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows-10

Hello there i am a full stack Laravel-php web developer and flutter-dart App developer and i am considering migrating from windows to linux because windows updates sucks + it sometimes install 3 languages packs that i don't use and slow and many things.
Note : i worked with parrot  , BackTrack and kali linux before so i have a pretty good understanding about the basics 
so i would like you to answer a few questions

1. is it a good idea ?
2. recommend distrbution for me
3. i use android studio IDE for working with flutter does linux has it
   with exactly the same features ?
4. i use wamp server does linux has it ?
5. my laptob has fingerprint sensor does linux has a driver or
   something to operate it ?
6. are there any system problems in linux (like blue screen)and are they
   solvable ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You should probably take a look at the [Superuser help center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Opinion-based questions and broad questions like this aren't appropriate for the site.

Comment: This will be closed shortly (by others) because the vast majority of questions require opinion based answers. This Q&A site is intended to have small-scoped, atomic-level single questions to which there are objective answers. See https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: sorry didnt know about it i thought this is the best place for it

Comment: Here and http://unix.stackexchange.com are good places to ask, but we do have limits on our scope and guidelines to follow, as explained before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

questions 1,2, and 6 require opinion-based answers or are overly broad, and can't be answered in this context.

Re: #3 Linux does have the [Android Studio IDE](https://developer.android.com/studio) available with the same features.

Re: #4 WAMP is Windows-specific and stands for
**Windows**, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.  LAMP is the Linux equivalent
**Linux**, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.
Apache, MySQL, and PHP are alive and well in Linux.

Re: #5  Drivers for many fingerprint sensors are available, but not all. It's wise to specify the make and model part number of your machine when asking questions about hardware.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 are up to you. My Kali and Ubuntu systems update as often as Windows and restart 1 or 2 times for each Windows restart.

5 and 6. Get a laptop with Linux fingerprint support (your own research). Properly made brand name laptop properly set up and maintained (and used) do not blue screen in daily use.